# I keep getting the error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: java

When i try to run this code I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
        at Oblig3B.main(Oblig3B.java:8)
```

Here is my code:

```
        import java.util.*;
        import java.io.*;

        class Oblig3B{
        public static void main(String[]args){

        OrdAnalyse oa = new OrdAnalyse();
Line 8. String filArgs=args[0];
        oa.analyseMetode(filArgs);
       }
       }

       class OrdAnalyse{
       void analyseMetode(String filArgs){


       Scanner input, innfil;
       String[] ord;
       int[] antall;
       int antUnikeOrd, antOrd;
       PrintWriter utfil;
       boolean sjekk;

       input=new Scanner(System.in);
       ord=new String[5000];
       antall=new int[5000];
       antUnikeOrd=0;
       antOrd=0;
       sjekk=true;

       try{
       innfil=new Scanner(new File(filArgs));

        //Here it reads the file, word by word.
        while(innfil.hasNext()){
        String ordLest=innfil.next().toLowerCase();
        sjekk=false;
            for(int i=0; i<ord.length; i++){
            if(ordLest.equals(ord[i])){
            antall[i]+=1;
            sjekk=true;
            }
        }
        if(!sjekk){

            ord[antUnikeOrd]=ordLest;
            antall[antUnikeOrd]++;
            antUnikeOrd++;
        }

        antOrd++;
        }
        innfil.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try{
        utfil=new PrintWriter(new File("Oppsummering.txt"));

        utfil.println("Antall ord lest: " +antOrd+ " og antall unike ord: "+antUnikeOrd+"  
        "+ ord.length);

        finnOrd(antall, ord, utfil);

        for(int i=0; i<ord.length; i++){
        utfil.println(ord[i]+("  ")+antall[i]);
        }

        utfil.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }


        void finnOrd(int[] antall, String[] ord, PrintWriter utfil){
        int teller=1000;
        for(int i=0; i<ord.length; i++){
        if(antall[i]>teller){
        teller=antall[i];
        }


        double tiprosent=teller*0.90;
        System.out.println(tiprosent + "   " + teller);
        for(i=0; i<ord.length; i++){
        if(antall[i]>tiprosent){
            utfil.println("Vanlige ord: "+ord[i]+"t("+antall[i]+" forekomster)");
        }
        }
        }
        }
        }
```

I'm not sure what I need to do to fix this error. I would appreciate any help I can get.

(I'm sorry if the code is a bit messy, not sure how I can fix it properly here on stackoverflow)

Thanks alot

Comment: How do you run your java program?

Comment: Did you pass it any arguments?  I'm guessing not.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I run the java program in command prompt

Comment: This declaration looks suspicious: String filArgs=args[0];  It means your array has no elements, so you can't access any of them.

Comment: Did you try to run this program from command promt with at least one argument?

Answer (score 1):

Java binds each argument passed to the application launched as an array to the `String[] parameter in your`main` method.

If you don't pass any arguments to the application launcher, for instance like

```
java Oblig3B
```

then the array bound will have size 0 and therefore

```
String filArgs = args[0];
```

trying to access the first element, at index 0, will fail. Check that you are actually passing arguments.

```
java Oblig3B "Some agument"
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't pass any command line arguments, so the `args` array is of zero-length.  So, attempting any array access will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Test the length of the `args` array before attempting to access it.  Here, make sure that the length is at least one before accessing `args[0]`.  Something like:

```
if (args.length >= 1)
{
    String filArgs=args[0];
    // Do your processing.
}
else
{
    // Handle the error here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running your program via command line you can pass one more parameter while running the command. If you are using an IDE e.g. eclipse you can pass the arguments by setting it via Properties -> Run/Debug settings

Basically,  `String filArgs=args[0];` is looking for first argument which doesn't exists